# React state (redux) updates, interface does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**SOLVED**

@jonahe helped me realise I was storing stale data in my component state resulting in a mismatch between the redux and component store.

@vs1682 pointed out that the store update check is relatively shallow so shouldn't be relied on for deep nested changes.

---

Original question:

I'm using promise based actions in redux and am running into the following issue: once my state updates (verified per redux logger) the visual component does not reflect this.

Action flow:

1. Form is submitted  (example: the bio property changes)
2. Smart component triggers a dispatch of an action
3. Action works as intended and triggers reducer
4. State updates well (reflected in redux logger in console)
5. Interface does not reflect the change (but the state certainly does)

As per the above I'm quite confident my actions and reducers are fine. I suspect I'm overlooking something in the redux > visual flow.

The below is isolated code. I took away jsx etc that is not relevant.

**Map state to props for the smart component:**

```
export default connect( store => ( { 
    user: store.user ? true : false,
    contacts: store.contacts
} ) )( ContactList )
```

**The smart component**

```
<Person person = { this.state.showingperson } />
```

**The person prop is set through:**

```
showPerson( e ) {
    e.preventDefault( )
    const showingperson = this.props.contacts.object[e.target.id]
    this.setState( { ...this.state, showingperson: showingperson } )
}
```

**The dumb component:**

```
export const Person = ( { person } ) => {
    return <div id="persontable" className="backdrop">
                <div className = 'modal col l6 m12 s12 center'>
                    <p>Bio: { person.bio }.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

**Edit: Reducer code:**

import moment from 'moment'

```
const contactsReducer = ( state = { array: [], object: {} }, action ) => { 

    switch( action.type ) { 

        case 'UPDATE_FULFILLED':
        case 'GETALL_FULFILLED':
            // action.payload is an array of contacts resulting from a transformed firebase call
            return action.payload ? action.payload : state
        break

        case 'CLEAR_FULFILLED':
            return null
        break

        default:
            return state

     }

 }

 export default contactsReducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit with new info from the comment section below**:

Is it the `<UserList />` or the `<Person />` component that doesn't show the updated data? Because it would make sense if `<Person />` didn't update considering it gets the data from the stale data in the internal state:

```
// this is used to set the internal component state
const showingperson = this.props.contacts.object[e.target.id]
// but after an update of the Redux state, this still points to the 
// old (not updated) object in the internal state
this.setState( { ...this.state, showingperson: showingperson } )
```

So the the internal state will contain a reference to the old object until the `showPerson` function is executed again.

---

**Old, wrong answer**:

This is commonly due to a mutation of the state in the reducer, causing Redux not to recognize that a change has occurred that should re-render the connected component. (Because of the shallow compare that [vs1682](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5616999/vs1682) mentioned.)

So in your reducer, make sure that you are not doing anything like this:

```
case UPDATE: {
  // mutation!
  state.contacts = action.payload;
  return state; 
}
```

But instead have something like this

```
case UPDATE: {
  // No mutation. Creating a new object!
  return {...state, contacts: action.payload};
  // or do the equivalent with Object.assign, 
  // Don't forget an empty object as first argument.
}
```

Comment: The reducer is immutable. I went through the usual troubleshooting to double check. Is the shallow check still an issue in a proper immutable setup?

Comment: It shouldn't be. But I would post the reducer code anyway just in case.  Especially nested state can be tricky

Comment: Edited with the code. Hope I'm overlooking something :)

Comment: Thanks. The reducer doesn't exactly follow convention, in that it seems to return quite different state "shapes" depending on the action. (For example, why does CLEAR_FULLFILLED return null, instead of going back to the initial state of `{ array: [], object: {} }` ? ) But I think that would likely result in an error in the console, instead of just not re-rendering.

Comment: Does the `action.payload`  have the same shape of `{ array: [], object: {} }`   (but with real data), so that it matches what your `showPerson` function expects?

Comment: Fair on the `null` return. Better to use the structure.

Comment: action.payload always has a `{ array: [], object: {} }` structure yes.

Comment: Ok, so a mutation of the state is probably not the issue then. Sorry for wasting your time with that, but that tends to be the issue so I kind of had to  at least try to rule that out first. You have some suggestions from @vs1682 that could work, but they seem a bit like workarounds. (But that's better than nothing).  Have you seen if your `mapStateToProps` function gets called after your dispatch your update?

Comment: Is it the `<UserList />` or the `<Person />`  component that doesn't show the  updated data? Because it would make sense if  `<Person />` didn't update considering it gets the data from the stale data in the internal state. (Until you press run the `showPerson` function again. ).

Comment: Ah you are right. I knew I was overlooking something. Indeed the `<Person />` component was the issue. I changed the structure to store the person id in the state, and passed the `store[stateid]` into the `<Person />`. Thank you for the second pair of eyes!

Comment: I tagged this post as the correct answer. Would you be so kind as to add the conclusion of this comment thread to the post for future reference?

Comment: Nice that you found the issue! Yeah, I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Connect method is highly optimized.
It **shallowly** compares the combined object returned from mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps methods to their previous result.
If they are shallowly equal the wrapped component won't update.

To check if this is the case you can add `componentWillReceiveProps` method to your wrapped component and check whether you are hitting this method.

Comment: Aah I assumed if was not so shallow. Is it advisable to manually trigger a re-render?

Comment: If want your component to render anyhow then you can pass `{ pure: false }` as fourth argument to connect. But that is not advisable as you'll loose all those heavy optimization provided by connect.
And your wrapped component will re-render everytime the store changes.

Comment: Hmm, yes that sounds unfortunate. Is there a way to trigger/force an elegant re-render after my dispatch succeeds? (It's a promise, chaining is trivial)

Comment: One other way to re-render your component is to pass it a new `ownProps`.   The `mapStateToProps` method takes a **second argument** as ownProps which is nothing but the props you pass to your connected component.            Ex. `<MyConnectedComponent newProp={someProp} />`, you'll get the newProp as your second argument to mapStateToProps method. And if your ownProps are different than the previous one, you are good to go.

Comment: It turns out that in this particular instance the issue was due to my own stupidity in where I stored the data (component state) causing stale data. See the edit to the OP. Thank you for your help!